# Should “dns-server” and “nameserver” tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have very similar tags about DNS name servers:

- [nameserver](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameserver) × 86
- [dns-servers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns-servers) × 41

Comment: Yes, they both have to do with DNS.

Answer (score 1):

These tags mean the same thing and should be merged. [nameserver](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameserver) should be the final tag name because it is the more popular.

Comment: You might explain what you mean by "canonical name" as that might not (though should) be apparent to everyone.

Comment: They should be merged into [tag:dns], a nameserver is part of DNS: DNS isn'a part of a nameserver.